# VHDL - image processing

Tags: image-processing, vhdl

I am doing my project on a Spartan 3 starter kit. I am processing an image stored on a PC.
Can you please tell me:

1. which kit should I prefer for processing my image for enhancement and pixel clarity ?
2. how to transfer an image from the PC to the starter kit ?
3. I am applying nufft algorithm - what actually is it ?